# No visible @interface for UIPresentationController declares the selector initWithPresentingViewController:presentedViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uipresentationcontroller

I was watching WWDC 2014 video [A Look Inside Presentation Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/228/)
I downloaded the source code (written in `Objective-C`) for the session, try to build it and I got this error:

> No visible @interface for UIPresentationController declares the
>   selector initWithPresentingViewController:presentedViewController.

Is the method suppose to be in the `UIPresentationController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the documentation of UIPresentationController the method is supposed to be 
`- (instancetype)initWithPresentedViewController (UIViewController *)presentedViewController presentingViewController:(UIViewController*)presentingViewController;` not `-(instancetype)initWithPresentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController presentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presentedViewController`. 
As soon as I changed that it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

No visible @interface for 'GIDSignIn' declares the selector 'signInWithConfiguration:presentingViewController:callback:'
Google SDK is updated there for in v6.2.x version signInWithConfiguration:presentingViewController:callback: is using but in updated version v7.0.0 using signInWithPresentingViewController:completion: — check this blow link - and check what version you are using .
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide